# Can you help me to simplify this algebraic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

How can I simplify this algebraic expression?

$$\frac{-2}{x^2-1}+\frac x{x+1} - \frac 1{x-1}$$

Comment: Can't access the link from where I'm at... They try to make it where the internet is secure.

Answer (score 1):

You have for some $A$ and $B$
$$\frac{-2}{x^2-1}=\frac{-2}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x+1}$$
You can then calculate $A$ and $B$ by multiplication with $x^2-1$ and comparison. After that you can simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{-2}{x^2-1}+\frac{x}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x-1} &= \frac{-2}{x^2-1}+\frac{x+1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x-1} \\
&=\frac{-2}{x^2-1}+1-\frac{x-1+x+1}{x^2-1} \\
&=1-\frac{2x+2}{x^2-1} \\
&=1-\frac{2}{x-1} \\
&=\frac{x-1+2}{x+1} \\
&=\frac{x+1}{x+1} \\
&=1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: You made a mistake going from the fourth line from the end to the third line from the end.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks @Bye_World

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{-2}{x^2-1}+\frac x{x+1} - \frac 1{x-1}$$
$$=\frac{-2+x(x-1)-(x+1)}{x^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{-2+x^2-x-x-1}{x^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{x^2-2x-3}{x^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{(x+1)(x-3)}{x^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{x-3}{x-1}$$
$$=1-\frac{2}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{-2}{x^2-1}+\frac x{x+1} - \frac 1{x-1}$$
$$=\frac{-2+x(x-1)-(x+1)}{x^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{-2+x^2-x-x-1}{x^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{x^2-2x -3}{x^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{(x+1)(x-3)}{(x+1)(x-1)}$$
$$=\frac{(x-3)}{(x-1)}$$

which is as simple as it can get.To check,  put $x=0$ and it simplifies to $3$ on either side of the equation.